# Trouble getting values from cookies in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies

In my app, i'm loading an url in a browser, with **WebBrowserTask**.
And in that url i give some details, and based on that details i'll be navigated to one among the two pages. What i have to is, i've to stop from navigating and get the data set in the cookie!! In android it is possible with **CookieManger.GetCookie(url)**.
But how could this be accompolished in windows phone using C#??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Web browser extensions for WP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowserextensions.getcookies%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Call GetCookies on a WebBrowser control, you cannot retrieve the cookies via a WebBrowserTask, When you call a phone task, the phone delegates that task to the OS until the task is complete.